# What is the difference between a 3 pin and 4 pin ultrasonic range sensor?

Tags: sensors, code-review

I am following a tutorial that uses an arduino and ultrasonic range sensor, it calls for a 3 pin module (Paralax 28015-ND) and I have a 4 pin module (http://www.electroschematics.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/HCSR04-datasheet-version-1.pdf).  The 3 pin seems to have one signal pin (both input and output) and the 4 pin has two separate signal pins (a trigger and echo).  How would I need to change the code and wiring if I am using the 4 pin?  Here is the code from the tutorial:

```
     /* Ping))) Sensor

   This sketch reads a PING))) ultrasonic rangefinder and returns the
   distance to the closest object in range. To do this, it sends a pulse
   to the sensor to initiate a reading, then listens for a pulse
   to return.  The length of the returning pulse is proportional to
   the distance of the object from the sensor.

   The circuit:
    * +V connection of the PING))) attached to +5V
    * GND connection of the PING))) attached to ground
    * SIG connection of the PING))) attached to digital pin 7

   http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Ping

   created 3 Nov 2008
   by David A. Mellis
   modified 30 Aug 2011
   by Tom Igoe
   modified again 02 Apr 2016
   by Randy Sarafan


   This example code is in the public domain.

 */

// this constant won't change.  It's the pin number
// of the sensor's output:
const int pingPin = 4;

void setup() {
  // initialize serial communication:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // establish variables for duration of the ping,
  // and the distance result in inches and centimeters:
  long duration, inches, cm;

  // The PING))) is triggered by a HIGH pulse of 2 or more microseconds.
  // Give a short LOW pulse beforehand to ensure a clean HIGH pulse:
  pinMode(pingPin, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(5);
  digitalWrite(pingPin, LOW);

  // The same pin is used to read the signal from the PING))): a HIGH
  // pulse whose duration is the time (in microseconds) from the sending
  // of the ping to the reception of its echo off of an object.
  pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
  duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);

  // convert the time into a distance
  inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
  cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);

  Serial.print(inches);
  Serial.print("in, ");
  Serial.print(cm);
  Serial.print("cm");
  Serial.println();
```

Comment: There are already libraries that do that for HC-SR04, the code is quite simple, just take a look at it and you'll see how you can modify your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple enough... instead of:

```
pinMode(pingPin, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(pingPin, HIGH);
```

You would have

```
pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
```

(of course you have to define `echoPin` to be whatever pin you choose to connect `ECHO` to).

And to save processing time you can have all your `pinMode()` calls in setup since there is no need to change mode on the fly any more.